Ubuntu server 22.04 installing Nvidia drivers with libnvcuvid1 without also installing GUI
I have had a working setup using tdarr inside a docker container for multiple months now, but it stopped working after an update to the container and my ubuntu packages.
Tracking down the issue led me to simply update the nvidia driver version I was using since it was no longer compatible with my version of ubuntu.
So far I can get the drivers installed, and have my GPU detected by nvidia-smi. But the issue I am facing is that the library libnvcuvid1 is missing from my system, and tdarr won't be able to transcode because of this.
While installing the nvidia drivers, I can see that libnvcuvid1 is listed in the recommended packages, but I don't want to install the recommended packages using apt because this will also install a bunch of stuff I don't need, including a GUI.
This is the command I use to install the drivers:
apt install --no-install-recommends nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-headless-550 nvidia-utils-550

I figured that after I run this command, I should just be able to run this one to install the missing package:
apt install libnvcuvid1

But this one gives this output:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libnvcuvid1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libnvcuvid1' has no installation candidate

I can't seem to find a way with apt to specify which recommended packages I'd like to install along my main package.
Is this something that can be done? Or are there any other alternative that would allow me to do that?

Are you looking for libnvcuvid.so.1? Install apt-file to search for packages that contain filenames: sudo apt update and sudo apt install apt-file and then update apt-file: sudo apt-file update and then search for what you need apt-file search libnvcuvid and it should return a list of packages that contain filenames that contain libnvcuvid. Strangely, it shows libnvidia-decode-550 and libnvidia-decode-550-server for me on 20.04 and when I search for this package at packages.ubuntu.com it shows up but when I click to view the files or download links, I get a 500 error for amd64.

Even more weird that the same packages, libnvidia-decode-550-server and libnvidia-decode-550 show up fine for 24.04 on the Ubuntu website but since I'm not running 22.04, I can't exactly verify that these packages really exist or that they contain the files you need. Everything points to these packages for 22.04 but I do not know why their website is throwing an error for additional information about these packages on Jammy.

It appears that you need the libnvidia-decode-550 or libnvidia-decode-550-server package. These packages appear to be almost identical, I can only guess that you would need the server version.
Run the following to install:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libnvidia-decode-550-server

In order to locate a package that provides a missing file, like libnvcuvid.so.1 in this case, use the apt-file utility to locate which package provides the file you need.
First, install apt-file:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-file

Then, update apt-file:
sudo apt-file update

Finally, search for the packages that provide the file you need:
apt-file search libnvcuvid

This should provide a list of packages that contain files that contain "libnvcuvid".
I intentionally made the search more generic than needed to return a broader range of results. You could, however, make the search more specific:
apt-file search libnvcuvid.so.1

The packages libnvidia-decode-550-server and libnvidia-decode-550 should be listed in the results and since you're using nvidia-headless-550 and nvidia-utils-550, I assume that one of the 550 associated packages is the one you most likely need.

Thanks for this! libnvidia-decode-550 was indeed what I needed. And thanks for the info about apt-file search. Weird thing is though, I had tried searching for the file using this command when initially investigating this, but I was getting no results. It probably was not fully updated... Thanks a lot!
